# Task disable on the parent Record

Tags: lightning, lightning-apps

I have to objects ,one is Account as a parent and contact as a child, In contact object  i created a task that task showing on the account. that task not display on the account ,how can i achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can, if you wish, [Disable Roll Up of Activities to a Contact's Primary Account](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customizeactivities_activities_account_rollup.htm&type=5). This will prevent Activities recorded on Contacts from showing at the Account level. It will not inhibit [other means](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=activities_view.htm&type=5) of linking Activities to the Account via the "Related To" field (`WhatId`), including Activities associated with Opportunities.

This change is made in Setup under Activity Settings. It has consequences and considerations; I recommend reading the entire document linked above.

Comment: I have a one more question can please explain on the (Inherited Sharing) Apex class and where we use it ?

Comment: Please open a new question for separate issues. I recommend reading the documentation first as it is thoroughly explained there